# Why am I having trouble calculating this ODE?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to compute solutions for
$$\frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial t^{4}}\mathcal{F}_{x}u(\xi,t)-|\xi|^{4}\mathcal{F}_{x}u(\xi,t)=0$$

```
DSolve[FourierTransform[Derivative[4][u][t], t, ω] - 
Abs[ω]^4*FourierTransform[u[t], t, ω] = 0, u[t], t]
```

But this doesn't seem to work out. Would someone be able to tell me how to properly do this so that I get something which looks like:

$$\mathcal{F}_{x}u(\xi,t)=c_{1}(\xi)e^{\cdots}+c_{2}(\xi)e^{\cdots}$$

**Edit**: I also tried:

```
Solve[LaplaceTransform[Derivative[4][u][t], t, ω] - 
Abs[ω]^4*LaplaceTransform[u[t], t, ω] == 0, u[t], t]
```

with no success.

I even cannot solve the equation $$\frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial t^{4}}u(\xi,t)-|\xi|^{4}u(\xi,t)=0$$

```
DSolve[Derivative[4][u][t] - Abs[ω]^4*u[t] == 0, u[t], t]
```

Comment: You have `=`; instead it should be `==`.

Comment: @corey979 Thanks, but I still have problems even having fixed that.

Comment: `DSolve` is for solving differential equations. Once you've taken the `FourierTransform` of the differential equation, you have an *algebraic* equation, which means that you can't use `DSolve`; you have to use `Solve`. Then, once you've solved for the Fourier transform of `u[t]`, you have to take the inverse Fourier transform, and you're done. However, if this is an initial value problem, I think you have to use either Laplace transforms or Fourier sine and cosine transforms instead. I don't think Fourier transforms are useful for solving IVPs.

Comment: @march See edit.

Comment: What exactly do you want to archieve? Because your ODE is solved perfectly by mathematica with `DSolve[D[u[\[Xi],t],{t,4}]-Abs[\[Xi]]^4*u[\[Xi],t]==0,u[\[Xi],t],t]`.

Comment: You have the wrong syntax in `Solve`. In addition, you're not solving for `u[t]`, you're solving for the *transform* of `u[t]`. Look up `Solve` in the documentation. Try this process with an equation that you *know* works via this method. Try to do the problem by hand, even! It might be one that's actually do-able by looking up (inverse) laplace transforms in a table, and *certainly* the algebra is easy after the transform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay i'm going to show how to solve your ODE in two ways.

1.: Mathematica's [`DSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html).
Lets define arbitrary starting values (not nessecary. Just to compare it with the second method) and our equation:

```
startValues={u[ξ,0]==1,(u^(0,1))[ξ,0]==1,(u^(0,2))[ξ,0]==0,(u^(0,3))[ξ,0]==0};
equation = D[u[ξ, t], {t, 4}] - Abs[ξ]^4*u[ξ, t] == 0;
```

Then we can simply plug it into DSolve with a Simplification afterwards (which is also not nessecary but makes the solution a lot more nice to look at):

```
FullSimplify[DSolve[{equation}~Join~startValues,u[ξ,t],t],{ξ∈Reals,ξ!=0}]
```

> {{u[ξ,t]->(ξ Cos[t ξ]+ξ Cosh[t ξ]+Sin[t ξ]+Sinh[t ξ])/(2 ξ)}}

2.: [`LaplaceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplaceTransform.html)

We use `LaplaceTransform[D[u[ξ, t], {t, 4}] - Abs[ξ]^4*u[ξ, t] == 0, t, ω]`
and plugin this into Solve (since the ODE is now a algebraic expression)

```
Solve[LaplaceTransform[D[u[ξ,t],{t,4}]-Abs[ξ]^4*u[ξ,t]==0,t,ω],LaplaceTransform[u[ξ,t],t,ω]]
```

We can now put this into [`InverseLaplaceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseLaplaceTransform.html):

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[Solve[LaplaceTransform[D[u[ξ,t],{t,4}]-Abs[ξ]^4*u[ξ,t]==0,t,ω],LaplaceTransform[u[ξ,t],t,ω]],ω,t]
```

Simplifiyng afterwards and adding our startvalues:

```
startValueRules = startValues /. Equal -> Rule;
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[
   Solve[LaplaceTransform[
     D[u[ξ, t], {t, 4}] - Abs[ξ]^4*u[ξ, t] == 0, 
     t, ω], 
    LaplaceTransform[u[ξ, t], t, ω]], ω, t] /. 
  startValueRules, {ξ ∈ Reals, ξ != 0}]
```

> {{u[ξ,t]->(ξ Cos[t ξ]+ξ Cosh[t ξ]+Sin[t ξ]+Sinh[t ξ])/(2 ξ)}}

Which is the same solution as above.

Plotting the solution from above (Attention: your ξ parameter is very volatile for $\xi\neq 1$)

```
Plot[(ξ Cos[t ξ]+ξ Cosh[t ξ]+Sin[t ξ]+Sinh[t ξ])/(2 ξ)/.ξ->1,{t,-15,2}]
```

> [image: Blockquote]